# How can I recursively read a directory in Deno?

Tags: file-io, deno

I'm trying to recursively read a file in Deno using [`Deno.readDir`](https://deno.land/api@v1.28.1?s=Deno.readDir), but the example they provide only does the folder given:

```
for await (const entry of Deno.readDir(Deno.cwd())) {
  console.log(entry.name);
}
```

How can I make this recursive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deno's standard library includes a function called `walk` for this purpose. It's available in [`std/fs/walk.ts`](https://deno.land/std@0.170.0/fs/walk.ts). Here's an example:

`/Users/deno/so-74953935/main.ts`:

```ts
import { walk } from "https://deno.land/std@0.170.0/fs/walk.ts";

for await (const walkEntry of walk(Deno.cwd())) {
  const type = walkEntry.isSymlink
    ? "symlink"
    : walkEntry.isFile
    ? "file"
    : "directory";

  console.log(type, walkEntry.path);
}
```

Running in the terminal:

```txt
% pwd
/Users/deno/so-74953935

% ls -AF
.vscode/    deno.jsonc  deno.lock   main.ts

% ls -AF .vscode 
settings.json

% deno --version
deno 1.29.1 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
v8 10.9.194.5
typescript 4.9.4

% deno run --allow-read main.ts
directory /Users/deno/so-74953935
file /Users/deno/so-74953935/main.ts
file /Users/deno/so-74953935/deno.jsonc
file /Users/deno/so-74953935/deno.lock
directory /Users/deno/so-74953935/.vscode
file /Users/deno/so-74953935/.vscode/settings.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Since that function returns an async generator, you can make your own generator function that wraps around `Deno.readDir`:

(Do note that the example provided will join the path and name, giving you strings such as `/directory/name.txt`)

```
import { join } from "https://deno.land/std/path/mod.ts";

export async function* recursiveReaddir(
  path: string
): AsyncGenerator<string, void> {
  for await (const dirEntry of Deno.readDir(path)) {
    if (dirEntry.isDirectory) {
      yield* recursiveReaddir(join(path, dirEntry.name));
    } else if (dirEntry.isFile) {
      yield join(path, dirEntry.name);
    }
  }
}
```

```
for await (const entry of recursiveReaddir(Deno.cwd())) {
  console.log(entry)
}
```

OR, you can use [recursive_readdir](https://deno.land/x/recursive_readdir@v2.0.0), which is a 3rd party library in Deno made for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to roll your own implementation, instead of using the standard library, here is a sample.

```
async function walk(path: string, callback: ({path: string, fileInfo: FileInfo}) => void) {
  const fileInfo = await Deno.lstat(path)
  callback({fileInfo, path})
  if (fileInfo.isDirectory) {
    const entries = await Deno.readDir(path)
    for await (let entry of entries) {
      await walk(`${path}/${entry.name}`, callback)
    }
  }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
await walk(rootPath, ({path, fileInfo}) => {
  console.log(`${path}: ${fileInfo.size}`)
})
```

You might want to also check for symlinks, handle permission errors, etc.  You may also change the `async/await` to leverage parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`recursive_readdir`](https://deno.land/x/recursive_readdir) for this:

```js
import { recursiveReaddir } from "https://deno.land/x/recursive_readdir/mod.ts";
import { join, extname } from "https://deno.land/std/path/mod.ts";

const markdownFiles = (await recursiveReaddir(join(".", "content"))).filter(
  (file: string) => extname(file) === ".md"
);
```